# Graph Theory and First-Order Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, first-order-logic

I'm studying some lectures on Graph Theory and I'm having some trouble translating the following statement to First-Order Logic.

> Every vertex has degree n-2, where n is the number of vertices on the
> graph.

Given P(x,y)="All vertex pairs that there's a path connecting them" and E(x,y)="There's an edge connecting the pair" (we cannot use the same variable i.e (x,x))

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Assuming that graphs are defined to not have loops, the sentence you want to translate is equivalent to "for every vertex $x$ there is exactly one vertex $y$ that is neither equal to $x$ nor adjacent to $x$."

Comment: @AndreasBlass that is a correct inference, but do we want to skip ahead to that or just frame (translate) the statement as given?

Comment: @Joffan How can we do that?  I'd be interested in seeing an answer that does this.

Comment: @AndreasBlass pretty much solved it right? The sentence is $\forall _x \exists_y (x\neq y \wedge \neg E(x,y)\wedge  \forall _z (z=y \vee z=x   \vee E(z,x)))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndreasBlass pretty much solved it in the comments for graphs with no self loops and no multiple edges. The sentence can be taken for instance as

$$\forall _x \exists_y (x\neq y \wedge \neg E(x,y)\wedge  \forall _z (z=y \vee z=x   \vee E(z,x))).$$

It says that for all $x$ there is a distinct $y$ not adjacent to $x$, and moreover all vertices $z$ not equal to $y$ or $x$ are adjacent to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For graph with no self loops:

$\forall x\in V,\enspace\nexists \text{ distinct } i,j\in V\setminus\{x\},s.t.\enspace\neg P(x,i)\wedge \neg P(x,j)$ and $\exists i\in V\setminus\{x\} s.t.\enspace\neg P(x,i)$

---

For graph where we allow loops:

$\forall x\in V,\quad \nexists \text{ distinct } i,j,k\in V,s.t.\quad \neg P(x,i)\wedge \neg P(x,j)\wedge \neg P(x,k)$ and $\exists \text{ distinct } i,j\in V s.t.\quad \neg P(x,i)\wedge \neg P(x,j)$

Comment: If $x$ is adjacent to neither $i$ nor $j$, then the degree of $x$ is at most $n-3$.

Comment: one of $i,j$ can be x itself? specifically, I have not assumed no self loops.

Comment: But suppose it isn't?

Comment: @saulpatz. I didn't get you. All i'm saying is that there exist 2 other vertices (but not 3 vertices) amongst the |V| vertices that every vertex $x\in V$ is not connected to. This gives us a degree of $n-2$ for each vertex.

Comment: The maximum degree of a vertex is $n-1$, not $n$.

Comment: ok i was considering the case for a graph to possibly have a self-loop. In that case, max degree is $n$ i suppose?